# How to return a dictionary with only palindromes of key + value

Tags: python

How to return a dictionary with only palindromes of key + value.(assignment)

```
def isPalindrome(dict1):
   newDict = dict1.copy().items()
   for key,value in newDict:
      result = key + value
      for index in range(len(result)):
         if result[index] != result[len(result) - 1 - index]:
            del dict1[key]
   return dict1
   
dictionary = {
   "kaj":"ak",
   "ado":"lescent",
   "gu":"ug"
}
print(isPalindrome(dictionary))
```

Current Output:

```
File "dict.py", line 7, in isPalindrome
    del dict1[key]
KeyError: 'ado'
```

Desired Output:

```
{'kaj': 'ak','gu': 'ug'}
```

Comment: Just for kicks, you can do it in one line: `{k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if k + v == ''.join(reversed(k + v))}`

Comment: Good to know, I'm new to dictionaries.

Comment: The above is a _dictionary comprehension_ in case you want to look it up. The general form is `{<key>: <value> for <item> in <items> if <condition>}`; the `if` is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deleting the key from the dictionary, the loop keeps on running and may try to delete it a second time, which raises the `KeyError` you are seeing.

Use a `break` statement after the `del` to stop as soon as the entry is deleted.